# SharePoint 2010 Server, facing memory overrun

Tags: windows-server

The SP2010 server in question has 60GB secondary memory with approximately 10GB of free space, but every now and then the remaining free space gets used up and the server goes down. There are some user defined SP Timer Jobs, Scheduled Windows Jobs and SharePoint back up activity that takes places at various intervals on this server. The back ups and logs use up lot of memory of the server but regular clean up ensure they don't exceed a certain limit. 
But there is one more problem with the server that the worker processes running seem to be consuming great deal of memory as you can see from the screen shot.

[image: Memory usage of the processes running on the server]

can someone please suggest steps that I should take in order to limit the danger of memory overrun. Currently I have a scheduled timer jobs that warns me if the memory goes down a certain limit, but it doesn't help solve the problem. I am looking to address the issue head on.

Comment: sorry, by Hard disc I meant Secondary memory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So Secondary Memory = Hard Disk, right?

RAM and Hard disk are (mostly) separate systems - don't mix the two up.

Hard Disk - you've got a server with 60 GB and on the screen shot you've got 1GB free! This is incredibly inefficient for a physical disk drive and you are risking massive [fragmentation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defragmentation) and poor performance. Hard disks are cheap in the grand scheme of things - put a bigger one in.

Ram memory - in general Windows, .NET and especially SQL server will use as much RAM as they can get their hands on (its faster that way) so if you meet the [SharePoint minimum hardware requirements](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262485.aspx) then stop worrying about it - your problems right now are almost certainly to do with the HDD.

Comment: one more question, the memory usage on the task manager actually points to RAM isn't it?

Comment: Yes - BUT you have 'paged memory' as well where the OS will report as having more RAM than it physically has and this is swapped out to the hard disk. Its all invisible but SLOOOOW - which is why having enough memory is cruicial to good perf. However - I still feel your big problem here is HDD and if you don't understand this stuff already you're going to get in a mess by meddling. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paging